# Go under the only folder in your directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, python-2.7, command-line

I have one folder in my current directory , I am trying to go under this folder so I did the following:

```
import os 
directory = os.getcwd()
for folder in os.listdir(directory):
    folder_name = folder
new_directory = directory + '/' + folder_name
os.chdir(new_directory)
```

But this seems to be too long , So any better solutions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as you said, there is only one folder in your current directory and no other file, you can do this:

```
os.chdir(os.listdir()[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have just one directory, you can do this (you no need more code, it just gets the first element in the single element list):

```
firstdir = os.listdir()[0]
os.chdir(firstdir)
```

Or even better:

```
os.chdir(os.listdir()[0])
```